# What is the highest video resolution achievable with my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, resolution, camera

I know how to use QuickTime to record a movie with my Macbook camera. It seems the resolution is 1280x720. Is this the maximum? Does this depend on the used software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your about this Mac - choose your marketing name of your mac and then look it up in the manuals.

https://support.apple.com/manuals

Most integrated cameras are 1080 and not 4k - so you will want to get a Logitech or DSLR camera for your mac if you care about higher resolution or better low light controls.

- https://www.wsj.com/video/series/joanna-stern-personal-technology/laptop-webcam-showdown-macbook-air-dell-xps-theyre-pretty-bad/

Comment: It seems the second link is nog working. It opens another page.